# SQL Server Bulk Load Error Message 4867

Tags: sql, bulkinsert

What exactly does "Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 1, column 5 (BlockId) mean?

I am trying to import the following line from a csv:

> 201-125,JAN12-201-Mon-Monday-01,20519311-JAN12-201-Mon-Monday-01,
>   Richmond, 2620401

The format flie line for this column is

> 5   SQLINT    0     4    "\r\n"     9   BlockId     ""

If I change the value for BlockId from 2620401 to 0, I do not run into this problem. Data was not exported using bcp.

TIA.

Comment: Are there any contraints on the table, IE referential integrity?

Comment: Just typical not null and primary key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Your field length of 4 is insufficient for an integer. Try using 12, which is the default.

```
5 SQLINT 0 12 "\r\n" 9 BlockId ""
```

Comment: I suspected so then went to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx and confirmed I should be using a length of 4. Also format file was created using bcp on existing table and if I run an insert directly against the table using those values, it takes it.

Comment: S, that was helpful but I also had to change the data type field.  I decided to explain this in details just in case someone else runs into the same problem.  MSDN does not document this properly.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be well spelt out on MSDN:

1. The format file describes the data that is being imported into the database.
2. The format file created using bcp WILL TYPICALLY need to be modified to give an accurate representation of the data, if this data was not exported using bcp.  Bcp defaults will NOT always be correct.

In this case, bcp created the following line

```
5 SQLINT 0 4 "\r\n" 9 BlockId ""
```

for my integer field within the format file.

If this data file was exported using bcp, then this field would be an SQLINT as this is what is defined in the database.

However, this data was NOT created using bcp.  It is just some manually created csv file.  Therefore, Host file data type of SQLINT is not correct.  For such data files, use a Host file data type of SQLCHAR.   Then, the Host file data length must correspond to the minimum length of characters representing this field in **the data file**.  If this field is going into a column of type [int] into your database, it is save to use a value of 12 for Host type data length.

So this correction is what was needed:

> 5 SQLCHAR 0 12 "\r\n" 9 BlockId ""